# remove lines which start with *(asterik) in powershell select-string output

Tags: regex, powershell

I am working on a code so that it find lines which has $control but should remove lines which start with * at first column

I am working with following but doesn't seem to work ..

```
  $result = Get-Content $file.fullName | Select-String $control | Select-String -pattern "\^*" -notmatch
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should provide filesample. is it a csv file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're escaping the wrong character. You do not want to escape `^` as that's your anchor for "starting with". You'll want to escape the asterix, so try this:

```
$result = Get-Content $file.fullName | Select-String $control | select-string -pattern "^\*" -notmatch
```

Also, if all you want is the lines, you could also use this:

```
Get-Content $file.fullName | ? { $_ -match $control -and $_ -notmatch '^\*'}
```